# Regex validation rule

Tags: regex, salesforce

I am having an issue with regex. I would like all my words to start with a capital letter. My field is a job title and I would like to have "Sales Manager" both words start with capital letter. My current regex is

```
NOT(ISBLANK(Title)), NOT(REGEX(Title, "[A-Z][']?[A-Za-z][A-Za-z !£$%&()@~#]*"))
```

Any help to get this second words starting with a capital letter? Thank you

Comment: Why the `[']?` and the `!£$%&()@~#]*"`?  Please provide more details about/examples of the type of strings you want to accept.

Comment: !£$%&()@~#]*" is to let people use special symbol in the field and not sure about  [']?. I tried your ReGex formula but I am having syntax error. I am about to get some help from Salesforce. I will keep you up to date. Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0):

This regex will only match an input if it only contains one or more capitalized words and no un-capitalized words:

```
^([A-Z][A-Za-z]+)(\s[A-Z][A-Za-z]+)+$
```

The `^` and `$` at the beginning and end of the pattern forces it to match the entire input or non at all. I don't know Salesforce or its API so not sure if you should include or remove them from the pattern.

I also didn't include the `[']?` and the `!£$%&()@~#]*"` because you had not explained why they are there.